# PI assignment using Abstract Class number

Tags: java, methods

I have an assignment where I need to use the Abstract Class Number to print out the value using the methods in the class Number.

Here is the code that is given and I just have to use the methods to print the PI value:

```
public class Pi extends Number {

    public static double PI = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950;

    private int intValue;        // PI rounded down to nearest int
    private long longValue;      // PI rounded up to nearest int
    private float floatValue;    // PI as type float
    private double doubleValue;  // PI as defined

/*
* TBI (To Be Implemented)
* The constructor assigns values to all of the instance 
* variables defined above. The values that are assigned
* to the instance variables are documented using comments
* when the instance variables are defined.
*/
public Pi() {

  // the expressions on the right side of each of the following 
  // assignment statements must use PI in them...
  intValue = ;
  longValue = ;
  floatValue = ;
  doubleValue = ;
}

/*
* TBI (To Be Implemented)
* Returns a String representation of this Pi object
* that is used as the output of this progam.
*/
public String toString() {
}

/*
* The following methods cannot be modified/deleted.
*/
public static void main(String[] argv) {
  System.out.println(new Pi());
}

public double getPi() { return doubleValue; }
}

/*
* the output of the program must look something like the following
*

byteValue(): 3
shortValue(): 3
intValue(): 3
longValue(): 4
floatValue(): 3.1415927
doubleValue(): 3.141592653589793

*
*/
```

I am just having a hard time starting this. I do not want anyone to do the program for please, just help me get started and how to implement the constructor and method.

Comment: is your question how to convert a `double` to an `int` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am not sure how to get started, I read through the Class Number and it says the constructor is just public Number(). How to I put that in my code.

Comment: I suggest you go back and ask for clarification

Comment: @ScaryWombat ok will do thank you

Answer (score 1):

The non-abstract `Pi` class extends the abstract [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) class, which has 4 abstract methods. Therefore, the `Pi` class must implement those 4 abstract methods. In addition, you must implement the code marked `To Be Implemented` in the `Pi` skeleton code that you were provided, and make sure that your implementation returns the expected output.